# How to find pid of Battery Service?

Tags: battery, processes

I am able to find the pid of System server using ps. And I can find info about the system server process through `/proc/pidof system_server`. But I dont see (or unable to find) the pid of the other Android System Services like Battery Service, etc..

Is there any way to find the pid of Android System Services ?